# Cyclic sets are to $S^1$-spaces as ? are to $G$-spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

From the article "[W. G. Dwyer, M. J. Hopkins, D. M. Kan, The Homotopy Theory of Cyclic Sets](https://doi.org/10.2307/1999909)" we know that, quoting from the abstract: "the homotopy theory of the cyclic sets of Connes [3] is equivalent to that of $\operatorname{SO}(2)$ spaces (i.e. spaces with a circle action)".

Are there similar statements for other groups $G$? E.g. for $G=\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: For $G$ a planar Lie group (e.g. $\mathrm O_2$, $\mathrm{Pin}_2^+$, $\mathrm{Pin}_2^-$), there is an analogue of the theory of cyclic sets and an equivalence of homotopy categories with $G$-spaces. See [Dyckerhoff-Kapranov](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5799), Theorem I.33(d).